# Pillow saving to BytesIO or StringIO KeyError: "JPG"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I have a Pillow Image object image, that I try to save to an IO.BytesIO object called temp using `image.save(temp, format="jpg")`

When I run this however, it gives a KeyError: "JPG" on this line `save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format is called `jpeg`, not `jpg`, so just use:

```
image.save(temp, format="jpeg")
```

See [Image file formats](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) for reference of possible values (or `PIL.Image.SAVE.keys()`)